# How to get the ignored row while IGNORE_DUP_KEY is ON on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have a `tmp` table shown below.

[image]

In the above table

- `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` is set to `ON`

and

- the `id` column is the primary key.

Said table has only one key. After inserting lots of data I will get the

> Duplicate key was ignored.

message because of some redundant data.

**I want to check which redundant row was tried to insert.** I checked the origin of the message it was `sys.messages`.

*Now, how to store the row which failed while the insertion attempt took place because of the duplicate primary key value?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture all the PK exceptions using a trace or you could capture which sql statements trigger the duplicate key message with an extended event.

In the following examples it shows you how to either capture the 'Exception' with a profiler trace, or capture the sql text executed that triggers the duplicate key message using an extended event.

The difference being that the 'exception' trace gets a row for each violation, which we could log to a file, and then read from that file.

**What could you capture?**

Before the user error message is returned,a PK violation occurs internally:

[image]

Which in turns gives the duplicate key value:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ignore_d__3BD0198E9F9BACEA'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ignore_dup_key'. The duplicate key value is (1).
```

While the user does not see this message, we could either capture these with a trace or an extended event.

[image]

---

**Profiler trace on the exceptions on the table**

[image]

**Add a filter**

[image]

**Capture the PK violations, even when  `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`**

[image]

**Error message captured**

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ignore_d__3BD0198E9F9BACEA'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ignore_dup_key'. The duplicate key value is (1).
```

**The problem here is that it can get messy real fast, as it gives a record per Failed value, so if 1 and 2 already exist**

```
INSERT INTO ignore_dup_key(a) VALUES(1), (2)
```

It gives two new exceptions in the profiler trace:

**1)**

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ignore_d__3BD0198E9F9BACEA'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ignore_dup_key'. The duplicate key value is (1).
```

**2)**

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ignore_d__3BD0198E9F9BACEA'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ignore_dup_key'. The duplicate key value is (2).
```

**Saving it to a table**

[image]

**Select from the new table**

```
SELECT *
  FROM [my_test].[dbo].[FindViolations];
```

[image]

**So, when Inserting 1000 Duplicate ID's, the logging will hold 1000 extra records**

```
  TRUNCATE TABLE [my_test].[dbo].[FindViolations];

  INSERT INTO ignore_dup_key(a) 
  select a from ignore_dup_key; -- 1000 duplicate records

  SELECT COUNT(*) from [my_test].[dbo].[FindViolations];
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
1000
```

[image]
ETC.

---

**Create the extended event**

[image]

Do not choose a template

[image]

**Select the error_reported event**

[image]

**Select the SQL_TEXT and username, and any additional things you would want to capture**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

**You could also add a filter, as to filter out non-duplicate key errors**
[image]

Comment: Can we capture for a specific database and table?

Comment: In the profiler trace window you can add additional filters, this is located at events selection --> Column Filters... . There you can add a databasename, and the table filter needs to be added to the TextData filter

Comment: In the case of Extended Events. What if we have bulk insertion ? or using BCP? How to get the exact record which failed. I tried with multiple insert statements and it gives all sql text. Can't find the exact insert statement which failed.

Comment: @VTVishwanath For the moment being I have not found the correct event for capturing all the different failed records, only the statement executed. For now, only by using the profiler trace and logging it to a table was I able to get all the records that failed through T-SQL.

Answer (score 6):

There would be additional overhead, but one option *might* be to create an `instead of insert` trigger which would check for duplicates first and route those to another table.

```
--demo setup
set nocount on
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[TestTable]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExtraInformation] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
) with (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[TestTableIgnoredDups]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTableIgnoredDups](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExtraInformation] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
 ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--create INSTEAD OF trigger
CREATE TRIGGER TestTable_InsteadOfInsert ON dbo.TestTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    --select rows to be inserted into #temp
    SELECT *
    INTO #temp
    FROM inserted

    --insert rows to TestTableIgnoredDups where primary key already exists
    INSERT INTO TestTableIgnoredDups
    SELECT t.*
    FROM #temp t
    JOIN TestTable tt
        ON tt.id = t.id

    --delete the duplicate rows from #temp
    DELETE t
    FROM #temp t
    JOIN TestTable tt
        ON tt.id = t.id

    --insert rows to TestTableIgnoredDups where duplicates
    --exist on the inserted virtual table, but not necessarily on TestTable
    ;WITH DupsOnInserted
    AS (
        SELECT id
            ,count(*) AS cnt
        FROM #temp
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING count(*) > 1
        )
    INSERT INTO TestTableIgnoredDups
    SELECT t.*
    FROM #temp t
    JOIN DupsOnInserted doi
        ON doi.id = t.id;

    ;WITH DupsOnInserted
    AS (
        SELECT id
            ,count(*) AS cnt
        FROM #temp
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING count(*) > 1
        )
    DELETE t
    FROM #temp t
    JOIN DupsOnInserted doi
        ON doi.id = t.ID

    --insert the remaining rows to TestTable
    INSERT INTO TestTable
    SELECT *
    FROM #temp
END
GO




--verify by trying to insert a duplicate row 
insert into testtable(id,ExtraInformation) values(1,'RowOne')
insert into testtable(id,ExtraInformation) values(1,'RowOneDup')

select * from TestTable
select * from TestTableIgnoredDups
```

---

Data from TestTable

```
| ID | ExtraInformation |
|----|------------------|
| 1  | RowOne           |
```

Data from TestTableIgnoreDups

```
| ID | ExtraInformation |
|----|------------------|
| 1  | RowOneDup        |
```

Comment: Can we use any system table to get the info? Because trigger will make server slow if we have large number of rows to be inserted.

Comment: @VTVishwanath - the only way I know to satisfy your requirement of (_Now how to store the record which is failed while insertion because of duplicate primary key._) is with an `instead of` trigger.